# What is shallow semantic processing?

Tags: syntax, terminology, semantics, psycholinguistics

What exactly is "shallow semantic processing", and how is it related to syntactic analysis?

Is it correct to say that syntactic processing of a text is the preliminary step for shallow semantic processing of the same text?

Comment: Shallow semantic labelling assigns semantic roles to nominal phrases. It must be preceded by some sort of syntactic analysis. It’s similar to dependency parsing but assigns roles rather than grammatical functions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. By saying "nominal phrases", do you mean basic syntactic units of a text (nouns, verbs, etc.)? Also, is there a paper that you would recommend that talks about the general procedures of sentence processing (syntactic analysis ---> shallow semantic processing ---> deep semantic processing --->... etc.)

Comment: I meant noun phrases and nominalised verb phrases. This paper is interesting and highly relevant: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P88-1012.pdf

Comment: Hello, thank you again for your comments. Is the shallow semantic processing (I am assuming this is a topic that is discussed in Psycholinguistics) somehow related to the feed-forward architecture of modular accounts in sentence processing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_processing)? sorry for asking lots of questions.

Comment: @Atamiri That paper requires the reader to be well-versed in first order logic. Hobbs is also pointing to his specific version of first order logic, which includes event variables. I fear that to begin to get anything at all form such a paper, one must be one of Hobbs graduate students.

Comment: @TimOsborne It's not a specific version of FOL, classical FOL has variables of any type. Event variables were introduced into NL semantics by Davidson long before Hobbs. In fact, the paper is very accessible, it's much less formal than, e.g., Montague. The paper is used in Saarbrücken to introduce BSc students to formal semantics because it's self-contained and very easy to follow.

Comment: Another relevant paper is this one, introducing [Shalmaneser—A toolchain for shallow semantic parsing](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2006/pdf/537_pdf.pdf)